# select and sum 3 highest values from id sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I would like to ask how to select 3 highest values and sum it in sqlite.

My table looks like this:

```
   ID           SKU         Price         
   -----        -----       -----
   John         Product1    100
   John         Product2    10
   Steven       Product3    20
   Rachel       Product4    100
   Jack         Product5    10
   John         Product6    10
   John         Product7    10
```

Easy solution would be to:  select Id, group_concat(SKU), sum(price) from my_table group by id;

This would give me overall picture, but what if I want to include only three highest values from each id and of course sum those three values? So the end result would look something like this:

```
       ID           SKU                              Price         
       -----        -----                            -----
       John         Product1,Product2,Product6       120
       Steven       Product3                         20
       Rachel       Product4                         100
       Jack         Product5                         10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (see example at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6aef5/2)):

```
select  ID, GROUP_CONCAT(SKU), SUM(PRICE)
from    test t
where   ID || '-' || SKU || '-' || Price in
    (
        select  ID || '-' || SKU || '-' || Price
        from    test t2
        where   ID = t.ID
        order by
                Price desc
        limit   3
    ) GROUP BY t.ID
```